# Rest api - create customer

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, curl, postman

I follow this Magento guide to work with Magento API REST (New Learner):
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/order-tutorial/order-create-customer.html

In this step I try run this `curl` line to create a new customer:

```
curl -X Post "http://domain/api/rest/default/V1/customers"\
    -H "Content-Type:application/json"\
    -d '{"username":"example", "password":"example"}'
```

and get "curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host".

Also I want to ask, can I call this request with Postman?

Comment: Yes you can use postman for this call you need to authorize the connection

Comment: authorize the connection via token ?

Comment: any guide i New Learner

Comment: Yes authorize the connection using token

Comment: You can also view this solution also here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170921/magento-2-rest-api-usage-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
token=$(curl -X Post "http://domain/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"\
-H "Content-Type:application/json"\
-d '{"username":"<admin_user>", "password":"<admin_password>"}')\;
curl -X POST "http://domain/rest/default/V1/customers"\
-H "Content-Type:application/json"\
-H "Authorization:Bearer "$token\
-d '{"customer":{"email":"example@example.com", "firstname": "Example", "lastname": "Example", "id_card": "123456", "tos": "Yes"},"password":"12345678"}'
```

Explain: according to the official document you provided,

```
token=$(curl -X Post "http://domain/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"\
-H "Content-Type:application/json"\
-d '{"username":"<admin_user>", "password":"<admin_password>"}');
```

is getting admin token, and then store the result to a variable called `$token`. And then

```
curl -X POST "http://domain/rest/default/V1/customers"\
-H "Content-Type:application/json"\
-H "Authorization:Bearer "$token\
-d '{"customer":{"email":"example@example.com", "firstname": "Example", "lastname": "Example"},"password":"12345678"}'
```

is creating customer part.

I've tested this on M2.1.7, but should be more or less the same on M2.2.

Comment: I understand now this idea  but still curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host > I test it with magento 2.2 . Thanks

Comment: It means your domain has problems, not the command itself.

Comment: token=$(curl -X Post "http://mysubdomain / <subdomain folder here> /rest/V1/integration/admin/token"\

Comment: Most probably it's due to wrong settings on `.htaccess` file. You can uncomment line 145 on this file and change to `RewriteBase /<subdomain folder>/`. The line number may varies on each version but it won't be far away.

Comment: Or method 2: You can try `"mysubdomain/<subdomain folder here>/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"` first. If OK then go for modify .htaccess method.

Comment: I try post thi with (postman) http://api.al-asnad.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token with admin (user-pass) - json and get token . after that I try to create customer via postman also and get code 200 . but when i check magento admin not find customer I add !

Comment: Any error log found on backend?

Comment: Please accept my answer if my command works, thanks.