# 404 Error in API response

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have to work with rest APIs in magento2. For that, I added Integration through backend system->Extensions->Integration and activated the same.

Then I tried to get a response of default API of

> http://local.magento.com/V1/customers/1/billingAddres

But it gives 404 error always. Is anything I'm missing to set. I also added a new user and assigned a new role with all permissions How can I activate the rest API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You have issue with your api url :**

**Your API URL should be like this -**
 http://local.magento.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1/billingAddres

**Where you must need to add index.php/rest before the api parameters.**

**index.php is optional** BUT **rest** **parameter is required in your url**.

**Fore more details refer this link** - [Magento 2 REST API usage with examples](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170921/magento-2-rest-api-usage-with-examples)

**Also for other parameters details refer this link** - http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Comment: Thanks...You are correct. But now I'm getting 'Consumer is not authorized to access %resources' error

Comment: @SIBHIS - Yes because you need to pass Accesstoken with your url - something like Bearer youraccesstoken , then and then it will works

Comment: As i said follow this url - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170921/magento-2-rest-api-usage-with-examples

Comment: Thanks a lot...it works. But index.php is not necessary in my case.

Comment: @SIBHIS - Yes as i have written above index.php is optional , but rest is must parameter... Happy to help - Keep helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was facing the same issue on the dev server and I just add the index.php before /rest/v1 and the issue get resolved.

Thank you!!