# Please suggest best solutions for API Authentication in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using `OAuth based authentication`,

But Its Showing

```
{“message”:”Consumer is not authorized to access %resources”,”parameters”:  
{“resources”:”Magento_Customer::customer”}
```

I am getting above error, Please try to resolve it

We are using below code

Please check screenshot

[image]

or you can see answer 6 code for OAuth-based authentication

[Magento 2 REST API usage with examples](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170921/magento-2-rest-api-usage-with-examples)

Comment: Please share code what are you calling for customer?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Please look My Question I have Edited my question please check